# Task Scheduler - Access non-local drives while running task not logged in

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks, scheduler, drive

I had a task in win scheduler that runs every minute. The task runs a .bat file which SVN updates a series of folders then executes a perl script (which in turn will run off several others). The output/'log' of the perl script (tagged by date/time) is sent to a shared drive, not local to the machine the task runs on.

The whole task works flawlessly until sending the log to the shared drive. Since the task needs to run every minute I figured it would be best to use the setting 'Run whether user is logged on or not' in task scheduler.. A box beneath is detailed 'Do not store password. The task will only have access to *local* computer resources.' Obviously this is not going to work for me, so I left it unchecked.

However the script does still not write to the shared drive, even when logged in. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to work around this? I also realised I could 'Run only when the user is logged in' (this DOES write to shared drive), but in that case I would need a definite way to ensure the account *never* logs off, and cannot be force logged off by other users (the computer is shared by a number of users, max two at a time).

Thoughts?

Comment: Are the drives mapped. Drive letters will never work. Use unc `\\server\share\path\file`.

Comment: @phd443322 Yes they are mapped, so at the moment the path looks something similar to:     
     N:\Pub\user\log\%mydate%_%mytime%.log      
How would that translate into the server format you suggested? Why does the above path work with 'Run only when user is logged in', but not with 'Run when user is logged on or not'?

Comment: @phd443322 Just to follow up, I just followed your advice and it worked perfectly, thanks very much

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[phd443322](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3724689/phd443322) has given already the right answer.

Mappings of a shared folders to drive letters are saved per **user account** in Windows registry if the network connection was made with default settings. Therefore every user using a computer can have different network drives.

There is the option *Reconnect at **logon*** to map the shared folder to a drive letter which is by default checked. But this option can be unchecked before creating the connection to map the shared folder to a drive letter just for current user session.

`net use /?` entered in a command prompt window outputs help of this command which is used to map a shared folder to a drive letter from command line or a batch file. There is the option `/PERSISTENT:{YES | NO}` whereby the default is `YES`. For example

```
net use Z: \\computer\share /persistent:no
```

connects a shared folder as drive Z: for current user session only.

This explains why [AMcNall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3699720/amcnall)'s failed with using a network drive in automated task.

Extra hint:

On using a laptop which is used in the office connected to company network, but also at home in a private network or no network, and finally also often in other networks, it is advisable to avoid an automatic network drive connection by Windows after logon in my point of view. It is better to use a batch file located somewhere on hard disk with a shortcut to this batch file stored in folder **Startup** of the user's Windows start menu with the property set to run the batch file with minimized window. The batch file contains for example:

```
@echo off
echo Checking availability of server/computer XXX
%SystemRoot%\system32\ping.exe -n 1 XXX >nul
if errorlevel 1 goto EndBatch
echo Map shared folder XXX\share to drive letter Z:
%SystemRoot%\system32\net.exe use Z: \\XXX\share /persistent:no
:EndBatch
```

Comment: Hi Mofi, thanks for the explanation as to why my original design didn't work, your answer should help anyone else who comes across the same issue as me!

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue - my task would run but not allow the called program access to a share even though I was asking it to run as a user who had rights.

The following helped and now it runs from within the Task Scheduler.  Below is taken from a Google search that helped.

Go to the Start menu.
Run.
Type secpol.msc. ...
The Local Security Policy manager opens.
Go to Security Settings - Local Policies - User Rights Assignment node.
Double click Log on as a batch job on the right side.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: this is nice one! Worked out for me

Answer (score 0):

The fix is to use the Subst command instead of Net Use.