# Multiple commands in batch file

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I have a batch file that I have scheduled to run in Task Scheduler, but it doesn't seem to run the second command "forfiles" when the Task runs.  Here is my batch file:

```
sqlcmd -S WEB01\SQLEXPRESS -U username -P password -i "D:\BackupPrograms\cslogsbackup.sql"
forfiles /P "Z:\Logs" /S /M *.bak /D -7 /C "cmd /c del @file"
```

Is there something that needs to go between the sqlcmd and the forfiles lines?
If I click on the batch file and run it manually it works fine, just does not delete the older files in the "forfiles" line when the batch files runs in the Task Scheduler.

Comment: I have found one thing.  I did a test and ran the scheduler on the server that holds the folder/files and it deletes the files fine.  So does anyone know why it will not delete files on a mapped network drive?

Comment: Take a look on answer of [Task Scheduler - Access non-local drives while running task not logged in](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24428597/3074564). You better use UNC path instead of `Z:` to avoid depending on existence of network drive connection. And if `sqlcmd` is not in Windows system32 directory, you specify this application better with full path and extension in double quotes.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I was able to run the scheduled task manually and it worked!  Now to see tomorrow if it continues to work without being logged in.  Thanks again!